# Build failing because of Specflow tests

Tags: c#, msbuild, specflow, azure-devops

Builds in Visual Studio Team Services build fail when we do not ignore specflow tests. All our tests return with a http status code 401 auth fail when actually expect a 200 or 422 etc. This only happens on our Visual Studio Team Services builds, when those tests are run locally they all pass. We specify the username and password in the specflow test, theyre hardcoded, so why does this not work or fail auth when being built on Team Services?

E.g.

```
2015-11-24T16:50:48.9936518Z ##[error]Error Message:

2015-11-24T16:50:48.9936518Z ##[error]     Expected: 200

2015-11-24T16:50:48.9936518Z ##[error]  But was:  401

2015-11-24T16:50:48.9936518Z ##[error]

2015-11-24T16:50:48.9936518Z ##[error]Stack Trace:

2015-11-24T16:50:49.0092775Z ##[error]at Test.Specifications.GetImageByIdSteps.ThenTheResultShouldBe(Int32 p0) in C:\a\1\s\Web\Web.Test\Specifications\GetImageByIdSteps.cs:line 36

2015-11-24T16:50:49.0092775Z ##[error]at lambda_method(Closure , IContextManager , Int32 )

2015-11-24T16:50:49.0092775Z ##[error]at TechTalk.SpecFlow.Bindings.BindingInvoker.InvokeBinding(IBinding binding, IContextManager contextManager, Object[] arguments, ITestTracer testTracer, TimeSpan& duration)

2015-11-24T16:50:49.0092775Z ##[error]at TechTalk.SpecFlow.Infrastructure.TestExecutionEngine.ExecuteStepMatch(BindingMatch match, Object[] arguments)

2015-11-24T16:50:49.0092775Z ##[error]at TechTalk.SpecFlow.Infrastructure.TestExecutionEngine.ExecuteStep(StepInstance stepInstance)

2015-11-24T16:50:49.0092775Z ##[error]at TechTalk.SpecFlow.Infrastructure.TestExecutionEngine.OnAfterLastStep()

2015-11-24T16:50:49.0092775Z ##[error]at TechTalk.SpecFlow.TestRunner.CollectScenarioErrors()

2015-11-24T16:50:49.0092775Z ##[error]at Web.Test.Specifications.GetImageByIdFeature.ScenarioCleanup() in C:\a\1\s\Web\Web.Test\Specifications\ImageGetImage.feature.cs:line 0

2015-11-24T16:50:49.0092775Z ##[error]at Web.Test.Specifications.GetImageByIdFeature.GetImage(String imageId, String userName, String password, String http_Status_Code, String[] exampleTags) in C:\a\1\s\Web\Web.Test\Specifications\ImageGetImage.feature:line 12
```

Comment: Where is the target of the test deployed? Chances are, the server running the specflow tests won't be able to see it.

Comment: How do you verify the authentication in your test? Connect to real database or use mock database?

Comment: All our specflow tests are with a real db, so we provide the actual username and password in the specflow scenario outline.

Comment: is the build failing, or is the test run failing? your question title is confusing

Comment: If the tests do not pass the solution does not compile leading to the build failing/not bilding/not compiling.

Comment: The tests cannot run if the solution does not compile. Which is it? They do not complie or they do not run, it can't be both?

Comment: The tests run and fail. If they fail, the solution does not compile. If the solution does not compile the build does not happen.

Comment: That still doesn't make sense. Why would you run tests before you compile code?

Comment: For continuous integration. To ensure nothing was broken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was happening because the transform of the connection strings happen on publish and not on build. So when it was being built, the server did not have access to the connection that was declared on my local connection strings (as the transform did not happen). I was assuming that on build the transform happens for the connection string. That is not the case, transform happens only on publish.